# Django - Simple User Register not working [Not saving to DB]

Tags: python, django, forms, view, user-registration

I have simple user registration page, but its not saving to the database.

**Issue: Register form displays, upon clicking submit button, doesn't do anything! Stays there (it should show a HttpResponse('User Registered') And save to db**

I've know I'm missing something, but what? ideas please.

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render


from django.views.generic import CreateView

from website.forms import RegisterUserForm

from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
# Create your views here.
class RegisterUserView(CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterUserForm
    template_name = "account/register.html"

    #  Overide dispatch func - check if the user is authenticated or return forbidden
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

        return super(RegisterUserView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # Overide form valid method behaviour
    def form_valid(self, form):
        #  False commit - don't save to db, locally cleaning users password first
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
        user.save();
        # Change to redirect - later one! 
        return HttpResponse('User Registered')

def Home(request):
    return render(request, 'account/home.html')
```

**Register.html**

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

{%  block title %}
Register
{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
    {% load static %}
    <link href="{% static 'forms.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{%  endblock %}
{% block heading %}
    <h1>Register</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
        <div class="bg-contact2" style="background-image: url('images/bg-01.jpg');">
        <div class="container-contact2">
            <div class="wrap-contact2">
                <form class="contact2-form validate-form">
                    <span class="contact2-form-title">
                        <h2> Teacher's Register </h2> 
                    </span>

                        {% csrf_token %}
                                {{ form.as_p }}


                    <div class="container-contact2-form-btn">
                        <div class="wrap-contact2-form-btn">
                            <div class="contact2-form-bgbtn"></div>
                            <button class="contact2-form-btn">
                                Send Your Message
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- 
    <h2>FORM</h2>
    <form action="{% url 'register' %}" class="contact2-form validate-form" method="post ">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form> -->
{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```
    from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        # Connect to the user model and select which fields we want input for user model
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']


    # Validate password matched / and clean them
    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data

        if cd['password2'] != cd['password']:
            raise ValidationError("Password don't match")
        return cd['password2']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the type in your button tag:

```
<form method="POST">
    <span class="contact2-form-title">
        <h2> Teacher's Register </h2> 
    </span>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <div class="container-contact2-form-btn">
        <div class="wrap-contact2-form-btn">
            <div class="contact2-form-bgbtn"></div>
                <button type="submit" class="contact2-form-btn">
                    Send Your Message
                </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

form tag should have an attribute action to tell where to take the data of your form to. So in Register.html you should add

action="{% url 'nameofyourviewgiveninurls.py'%}"

in your form tag

Comment: do add the submit button as Rohan Baddi told